# Button click handler is not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code. Can anybody tell me what am I missing? Thanks in advance.

```
 <!DOCTYPE>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button id="button1">AddRow</button>    
        <script>
           $(document).ready(function(){
               $('#button1').click(function(){    
                   alert("button1 clicked");
               });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What means `and it's not working.`? What should your code do?#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Error line:

```
<script="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Your `script` tag is not well formed. As a result `jQuery` is not loaded and you get error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

*Solution*: Add a space after `script` and use `type` before `="text/javascript"`,

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button id="button1">AddRow</button>    
        <script>
           $(document).ready(function(){
               $('#button1').click(function(){    
                   alert("button1 clicked");
               });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: thanks man....my stupid mistake